# Default C++ definitions in body or header files

Tags: c++, c++11

Scott Meyer states in *Effective C++: Item 30: Understand the ins and outs of inlining* that constructors and destructors are often worse candidates for inlining.

Defining functions inside a class definition, requests (not commands) them implicitly to be inline. Depending on the quality of your compiler, the compiler decides whether or not (explicitly or implicitly) defined functions be actually inlined or not.

Taking all these into account, is it a better practice to explicitly define empty/copy/move constructors, copy/move assignment operators and destructors as default (i.e. with the `default` keyword) inside the body files than inside the header files? After all, `default` deals purely with implementation as opposed to the dual `delete`?

Comment: It makes zero sense to define a non-inline *empty* function

Comment: Modern compilers can inline the functions even if you define them in the .cpp file. You have to trust your compiler! Having said that, I believe it is unusual to have `= default` functions defined separately.

Comment: @n.m. which *empty* function? Nor a constructor or destructor is an empty function, compilers will add lots of code even if these functions would appear empty to the user.

Comment: @BoPersson No! Compilers cannot do that. Only at linking state if LTCG (ms compiler) or LTO (gcc/clang) is enabled. Still, by having lots of stuff inline you make your compiler work harder than necessary and produce giant obj files with duplicated code.

Comment: @Pavel - It's just a matter of definition. The LTCG option actually invokes the compiler after (or during) linking, so it is still the compiler that generates the inlined code. When I say "Modern compilers" I might mean "Modern implementations of the C++ language".  :-)

Comment: "is it better practice to explicitly define **empty** /copy/move constructors" If it's not empty, what is your question about?

Comment: @BoPersson yes, it's basically properly done amalgamated compilation. With moders compilers (e.g. with LTO/LTCG enabled) it makes even more sense to move as much code as possible out of headers.

Comment: @n.m. An "empty constructor" is C++ terminology, despite its name, still far from a noop after compilation.

Comment: Just a point about terminology: when you define any member function inside the class' definition, the member function is implicitly an inline function. Being an inline function has two consequences: first, it's okay to have the same function defined in more than one translation unit, provided the definitions are "the same"; and, second, it requests that the compiler expand the function in place (i.e., inline it). The latter is where the name came from, but these days it's not particularly important. Nevertheless, such a function **is** an inline function, even if it doesn't get inlined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without ever reading "Effective C++: Item 30" I can definitely tell that it makes perfect sense to define empty-looking ctors/dtors inside .cpp:

```
// MyClass.h:
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    ...
}

// MyClass.cpp:
MyClass::MyClass() = default;
MyClass::~MyClass() = default;
```

This might look like waste for digital ink, but this is exactly how it has to be done for heavy classes that have large inheritance list or lots of non trivial members.

Why do I think it has to be done like this?

Because if you don't do that, then in every other translation unit where you create or delete MyClass compiler will have to emit inline code for entire class hierarchy to create/delete all members and/or base classes. In giant projects this is usually one of main reasons for builds that takes hours.

To illustrate, compare generated assembly [with non-inline ctor/dtor](https://godbolt.org/g/RDLhEb) and [without](https://godbolt.org/g/ElcKmq). Not that if you have multi-level inheritance with virtual classes then amount of generated code grows very fast. Some call it C++ code bloat.

Basically if you have inline function in your class and you use that function in N different cpp files (or worse in some header files that are used by many other cpp files) then compiler would have to emit that code N times in N different object files, and then at link time merge all these N copies into one version. This rule applies basically to any other function, however, it's not very common to make large function inline in header files (because it's just bad). The issue with constructors, destructors and default assignment operators etc is that they may look like empty or no c++ code at all, while they actually need to perform that same operation recursively for all members and base classes and all of that results in very large amount of generated code.

Comment: And thus definitely applies to copy/move constructors and assignment operators?

Comment: @Matthias yes, if you copy some object of some class in many other cpp files then compiler would have to emit that code multiple times (which takes time to compile and generate), and then takes time to link and merge duplicate code.

Comment: You may have to choose between defining members in headers (which allows for natural optimization at compile time, without LTO) and using LTO/LTCG, which can also take a lot of time on large projects. Personally I define many simple functions in headers (especially trivial things like abstract templates/traits, where you naturally expect inlining, copy elision etc.), and large implementations in CPP files, which only expose a high-level interface (no low-level interop across object files) ; without LTO.

Comment: @maxbc correct. But ctors/dtors, default assignments etc are far from trivial even though they might look like they are no-ops and that's the point.

Answer (score 4):

Another use case of defining a destructor `= default` inside the body file, is the [PImpl idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) in combination with `std::unique_ptr`.

**header file**: example.hpp

```
#include <memory>

// Example::Impl is an incomplete type.

class Example
{
public:
    Example();
    ~Example();
private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr< Impl > impl_ptr;
};
```

**body file**: example.cpp

```
#include "example.hpp"

struct Example::Impl
{
    ...
};

// Example::Impl is a complete type.

Example::Example()
   : impl_ptr(std::make_unique< Impl >())
{}

Example::~Example() = default; // Raw pointer in std::unique_ptr< Impl > points to a complete type so static_assert in its default deleter will not fail.
```

At the point in the code where `std::unique_ptr< Impl >` is destroyed, `Example::Impl` must be a **complete** type. Therefore, implicitly or explicitly defining `Example::~Example` in the header file will not compile.

A similar argument applies for the move assignment operator (since the compiler-generated version needs to destroy the original `Example::Impl`) and for the move constructor (since the compiler-generated version needs to destroy the original `Example::Impl` in case exceptions).